# Running Rscript with UTF-8 on Windows 10

Tags: r, rscript

Instead of opening Rstudio or similar to run my R scripts I have gotten into the habit of running scripts with `Rscript.exe` from the command line. Works great except when the file I feed Rscript.exe has non-ASCII characters. If my Rscript subsequently calls other Rscripts there are no issues. Concrete example:

I have two files

```r
# test.R
print(intToUtf8(230))
print("æ")
```

```r
# run_test.R
source("test.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Now if I go to the command line and run: `[...] \R\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe test.R` I get:

```r
[1] "æ"
[1] "Ã¦"
```

My current solution (which I want to get around): `[...] \R\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe run_test.R`

```r
[1] "æ"
[1] "æ"
```

Possibly relevant info:

- I would like to continue saving my script files with "UTF-8".
- R version 4.0.2
- Tried running scripts from Powershell, Command Prompt, Git Bash. Always the same result.
- Locale:

```r
Sys.getlocale()
# "LC_COLLATE=Icelandic_Iceland.1252;LC_CTYPE=Icelandic_Iceland.1252;LC_MONETARY=Icelandic_Iceland.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Icelandic_Iceland.1252"
```

Comment: Try creating a .Rprofile file containing `options(encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: @HongOoi Tried adding it to the top of the script and to my .Rprofile, but neither fixed the issue.

Comment: You could also try `Sys.setLocal("LC_CTYPE", "UTF-8")`

Comment: @HongOoi tried `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "UTF-8")` in both places but didn't work. `OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored`